# Golf my iteration function

Tags: code-golf, math, tips, recursion, ruby

Here is my ungolfed Ruby code for a function I want to try and golf:

```
Iter =-> k {
    str = ""
    (0..k).map{|m| str += "-> f#{m} {"}
    str += "f#{k}.times{f1 = f0[f1]};f1"
    (2..k).map{|m| str += "[f#{m}]"}
    eval(str + "}" * (k+1))
}
```

The best I can do to golf this is essentially shortening variable names, removing spaces, and rearranging the code to reduce the amount of loops:

```
I=->k{s="f#{k}.times{f1=f0[f1]};f1"
(2..k).map{|m|s+="[f#{m}]"}
(0..k).map{|m|s="->f#{k-m}{"+s+?}}
eval s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsIwEADveUVZL5WQ0PQqiee8YdlDhQYkBoqxUtnu22M9ep0Z5rnePq1Fb0Lm6iGdOIt93ctcOTmfBkyO5JIcqH60Np9tmRbey161BzzqIgSi@uHPeTDhdzJFGHTVVxE1v6dHV6UtXcSRMKIjQhM23rQTOlD7Ag)

This function can be compacted so that it avoids a lot of defining new functions. You can think of it like this:

$$\operatorname{Iter}(k;f_0,f_1,\dots,f_k)=f_0^{f_k}(f_1)(f_2)(f_3)\dots(f_k)$$

where

$$f^n(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\dots f(}_nx)\dots))$$

denotes function iteration. The types of arguments are given as:

$$\operatorname{Iter}(\text{int};\dots,(\text{int}\mapsto\text{int})\mapsto(\text{int}\mapsto\text{int}),\text{int}\mapsto\text{int},\text{int})$$

That is, the last argument is an integer, and each previous argument maps from T to T, where T is the type of the next argument on the right.

It is true that accepting all arguments at once would allow me to golf the above code further:

```
I=->k,*a{a[-1].times{a[1]=a[0][a[1]]};(2..k).map{|m|a[1]=a[1][a[m]]};a[1]}
```

However, the issue is that I need to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) this function. This way, I may treat objects such as

$$\operatorname{Iter}(k)(f_0)$$

as their own object, and thus be able to pass this into Iter(k) to get things such as

$$\operatorname{Iter}(k)(\operatorname{Iter}(k)(f_0))$$

As a specific example of what this function does, we have

\begin{align}\operatorname{Iter}(2)(\operatorname{Iter}(1))(x\mapsto x+1)(2)&=\operatorname{Iter}(1)(\operatorname{Iter}(1)(x\mapsto x+1))(2)\\&=\operatorname{Iter}(1)(x\mapsto x+1)(\operatorname{Iter}(1)(x\mapsto x+1)(2))\\&=\operatorname{Iter}(1)(x\mapsto x+1)(2+1+1)\\&=\operatorname{Iter}(1)(x\mapsto x+1)(4)\\&=4+1+1+1+1\\&=8\end{align}

> I'm interested in seeing if this can be golfed down further, with the restriction that the arguments must be curried in the order provided.

Comment: Mind if anyone explain the "unclear" close vote? I really did try my best to explain everything, so if there's any part that's unclear, just ask.

Comment: It's a bit unclear because you have tagged this "tips", but it's written almost like a challenge. I'd remove the tips tag and make it more clearly a challenge. Otherwise, perhaps make it clear that you're looking for golfing tips for this specific program. Your last statement makes us unsure of what you want.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in J `>:` is the increment function, and your example `I[2][I[1]][->x{x+1}][2]` can be written `>:^:2^:3 (2)`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7azirIzirIz/a3KlJmfkK6QpGP0HAA "J – Try It Online").  `^:` is the power of conjunction, and iteratively applies the verb on its left the number of times specified by the number on its right, with 1 being normal application `f(x)`, 2 being `f(f(x)`, etc.

Comment: @mbomb007 okay, I cleared that part up.

Comment: @lirtosiast Thanks and done

Comment: @Jonah interesting syntax, though it seems I'm no longer looking for non-Ruby answers. Am still a bit curious as to how you would write something like `I[1][I[2][I[1]]][s][2]`.

Comment: Apparently with your golfed code (and my solution that improves on your golfed code) hits an infinite loop when you change the last argument to `3` instead of `2`... This shouldn't happen, right? Or am I missing something? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcyxCsIwEIDhPU9RzqUSEpo6SuKcZzhuqNCAxEAxVSrXe/aoo/P/8T@e13dr0ZuQuXpIB85i11uZKyfn04DJkZyTA9WP1uajLdPCe9mr9oBfXYRAVD/8NQ8m/E6mCIOu@iKi5td076q0pYs4EkZ0RGjCxpt2Qnii9gE "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @ValueInk that's not an infinite loop. The issue there is the end result is 3 times 2^402653191 (3<<402653191)

Comment: That definitely means I missed something lol... I thought the output was going to be something closer to, I don't know, `12`.

Comment: @ValueInk Let `s[n] = n+1`. See that `I[1][s][n] = 2n` and `I[1][I[1][s]][n] = n2ⁿ = n<<n`. From that point, you can directly compute your example with `n = 3; 3.times{n <<= n}`...

Comment: Erm, miscalculation, it ought to be `3 << 402653211`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```ruby
I=->k{eval ("->f%d{"*-~k+"f%d.times{f1=f0[f1]};f1"+"[f%d]"*~-k+?}*-~k)%[*0..k,k,*2..k]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEEWvUgYKNemEpltpXOcMwywUOyCjIFalJaRXj3H1H@/91@eylRInDJrm7/nedIBB2msCg7taqOjet8e8JPGTDCSe81E8WKCaGMyOak/5fz60ZAbntNfejHU5l2cTaWSK5JkJw5pW6zNXVX4)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>94</s> 96 bytes

Using loops to do concatenations that followed such a simple pattern felt cumbersome, so I utilized the creative use of `join` instead, further golfed by the fact that `array*str` is equivalent to `array.join(str)`

*+2 bytes to fix a typo I made that just so happened to return the same result on the test example by chance.*

```ruby
I=->k{eval"->f#{[*0..k]*'{->f'}{f#{k}.times{f1=f0[f1]};f1#{"[f#{[*2..k]*'][f'}]"if k>1}"+?}*-~k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpNCoMwEEDhq0hcCJEEx20xXecMwywsOCDTQumPWIbp1WNol@/xPd6XTyl5Ckl02earC4lbRT/EKOQ7rdmZ1iUWX@tteSrDxAMykJ0YWnX48@PfE1ZObuVGEpjrz@bDV6zcm4wjYUYgwpB23Xswqqsc)

Comment: Oh wow I never knew you could use `array*str` in Ruby, and like that! So much to learn...